# jquery: help center variable size div on image hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little problem I don't understand. I made a jsfiddle to illustrate it.

http://jsfiddle.net/sandrodz/czfGy/9/ (updated to include images)

So when user hovers on image it should div is revealed which contains text "sunny cloudy" this massage varies so it can be smaller or larger.

I want it centered over the image. But unfortunately my jquery logic doesn't work correctly and hover appears shifted to the left.

Any ideas?

```
$("#tempicon img").hover(function() {
    divW = ($(this).next("div").width() / 2) - ($(this).outerWidth() / 2);
    $(this).next("div").css({marginLeft: -divW }).animate({ opacity: "show" }, "fast");
}, function() {
    $(this).next("div").animate({opacity: "hide"}, "fast");
});
```

To add to the confusion, I use same exact code on the other div and it works perfectly :S

Comment: Without an image in your fiddle it's hard to help.

Comment: @j08691 Hi, I tried to fix all images. http://jsfiddle.net/sandrodz/czfGy/9/ Note problem is only horizontal alignment, arrow should point directly over the sun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try my working [update](http://jsfiddle.net/czfGy/12/) (Firefox/Chrome). The **`middle of image - width/2 of label`** is correct.

What I did: I added variable names which should help while figuring out the positioning. Also, I change the `marginLeft` to simply `left`. With this calculation, you should be ok as long as everything (image and label `div`) is inside the same ["offset parent"](http://jqapi.com/#p=position) and you don't change the `position` property of one of them.

Comment: Then try [update 12](http://jsfiddle.net/czfGy/12/). I reset everything to your version (9) and pasted the JavaScript from 12, only changing the selector for the label, CSS and HTML are unchanged.

Comment: fantastic! thanks :) but why mine didn't work? it kinda made sense in my twisted head :)

Comment: I think good variable names (even something like `halfOfLabelDivsWidth`) help a lot with something like your example. With them you can make sure that a variable really contains the correct value (the one it is named after) and not think about that anymore while figuring out the rest.

Comment: Yes, got it. But is not marginLeft better than left? I usually avoid calculations based on the side of the browser window. But in this case it doesn't matter right?

Comment: Really depends on the surroundings/the offset parent (i.e. the element that the position depends upon). I usually try to avoid negative margins. Also, `left` is for positioning and `margin` is for... well margins. :)

Comment: Thank you for explanations etc. Really learning from experienced people is awesome.